# tenantService not available Grails 3.3.2 gorm 6.1.8.RELEASE

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Reading this intro to [gorm 6.1](http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/whatsNew/manual/) I found reference to the TenantService, which seems to do exactly what I want, but it doesn't seem to be injected. Attempting to call a method on it, I get a null exception, and if I run the following code there is no trace of TenantService in the long list of beans.

```
def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
ctx.beanDefinitionNames.sort().each { println it }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find the hibernateDatastore bean was available though, and I could get access to the tenantService by doing the following

```
def tenantService = hibernateDatastore.getService(TenantService.class)
```